# Expose a win32 application as a service to a UWP applications

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a win32 (non uwp) C# application which I’d like to expose to UWP applications (both processes run on the same machine). I'd like to expose the win32 application as a service, with bi-directional communication.

I tried using the sample from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample), but I have two issues with it:

1. I’m receiving ServiceClosed notifications in my win32 application (also occurs in the example).
2. I have to hard code a string in my service (PackageFamilyName in the AppServiceConnection), per client (I’m assuming that I require a reversed example, where the win32 application provides the service, instead of being a client).

I also tried to add a UWP app service to [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/HelloWorldSample). Couldn't get it to work.

Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Requirements:

1. The UWP client shall register for events from the win32
   application.
2. The events shall be fired in high rate from the win32 application (30-60 times in a second).
3. A UWP c++ client should be able to consume the service exposed by the win32 application (I think this negates SignalR as a solution).
4. The win32 application cannot be converted to a UWP application.

---

Edit:

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1607, OS build 14393.577 and VS2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Steps for repro in the AppService Bridge Sample:

In program.cs, below this line:

```
connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
```

Add this line:

```
connection.ServiceClosed += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("ServiceClosed!");
```

Press start, type "Desktop Bridge AppService Sample" and run it. Start debugging BackgroundProcess in VS2015 (do not launch the BackgroundProcess from the UWP application).

Wait for ~10 seconds until a message of "ServiceClosed!" appears.

Note that after this disconnection the UWP application can still send messages to the win32 application, but if you add code in the win32 application to send messages back to the UWP application they shall not be sent successfully.

Comment: I just tested the AppService Bridge Sample on windows 10.14393+VS2015 Update 3, it worked well. Could you please update the question to provide the detailed environment information? Like OS version, IDE version

Comment: I've edited the question with an answer to your question + details for repro

Comment: With regards to #3, [there is a C++ SignalR client](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp).

Comment: Will that C++ SignalR client work in a UWP C++ application?

Comment: @Tom You launch the UWP sample from Start menu, how did you debugging the BackgroundProcess in VS2015? Are you attaching the process in VS?

Comment: Yes, I run the UWP sample from the start menu (see my edit in the answer above). Also, I set the BackgroundProcess as the start up project in VS2015 and then hit Debug -> Start Debugging (F5)

Comment: I can let my Win32 to handle the requests from my UWP app. I use the UWP as a host app of app service, and my UWP launches Win32. I find I need to wait for 5 seconds after Win32 application launches to be able to send the request, is that possible your ServiceClosed actually an error indicating the connection is not ready yet?